# How can i add ScrollView to layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to add scrollview layout to this layout :

[image: a busy cat]

I'm getting this error.

```
ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can put one vertical ``LinearLayout`` into ``ScrollView`` and add other views/layouts into it.

Comment: I already tried it but I will try it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scrollView can not contain more that one child inside him

**WRONG**

```
<ScrollView>
   <LinearLayout>
       xxxxx
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       xxxxx
   </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

**RIGHT**

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       xxxxx
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
       xxxxx
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
<ScrollView>
```

*Only one direct child.*

Comment: When I added a Linearlayout as a only one direct child, in this situation all design is breaking.

Comment: Ok thanks. I solved my problem. This problem is absolutely about my mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can only add one View within ScrollView . So add a LinearLayout say L1 within ScrollView and within that LinearLayout(L1) , add all other Views .